# Mysterious why I am getting "CompressionStream" is not defined error at compile time

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors

I am puzzled why I am getting a compilation error when I try to use CompressionStream in my react app.
Same for DecompressionStream. I googled for this and have not seen a single hit with people having the same problem.
code snippet is :
async function compressFile(file) {
const readableStream = await file.stream();
const compressedReadableStream = readableStream.pipeThrough(new CompressionStream('gzip'));
const compressedFile = await fileSave(new Response(compressedReadableStream), {
fileName: file.name + '.gz',
extensions: ['.gz'],
});
return compressedFile;
}

and error message at compile time is   Line 262:73:  'CompressionStream' is not defined  no-undef

This is driving me nuts

First I suspected a browser problem, but then I realized that it was at compile time. So has nothing to do with the availability of the Web API function that existed back in 2020.
So I am clueless what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Support for CompressionStream was only added to Firefox and Safari [very recently.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompressionStream/CompressionStream)

Are you trying to compile your app for a build target that doesn't support it? If so, you could change your build target to only include the most recent versions of Safair and Firerfox. (The details of how to do this will differ depending on what you are using to build your app - [here are instructions for vite](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-target)). However, this will mean it won't work for anyone using older versions of those browsers.